# How do I use proxy.ModifyResponse?

Tags: go, reverse-proxy, httpwebresponse

I've implemented the most basic Reverse Proxy to pull a page and then add some content to the body.  Unfortunately my attempt to add to the html isn't taking effect.  The code below just shows the original page but without the "monkeys" I prepended to the response.  What additional calls are needed to get this to work? I eventually want to use this to replace css for custom css.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "bytes"
)

type Director func(*http.Request)

func (f Director) Then(g Director) Director {
    return func(req *http.Request) {
        f(req)
        g(req)
    }
}

func hostDirector(host string) Director {
    return func(req *http.Request) {
        req.Host = host
    }
}

func UpdateResponse(r *http.Response) error {
    doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(r.Body)
    if err != nil{
        //log.New("Research")
        log.Fatal("Bad doc %v", err)
        return err
    }
    html, err := goquery.OuterHtml(doc.First())
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal("Bad html %v", err)
        return err
    }
    fmt.Printf("Body %v", html)
    r.Write(bytes.NewBufferString("monkeys"+html))

    return nil
}

func main() {
    url, _ := url.Parse("http://cnn.com/")
    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(url)

    d := proxy.Director
    // sequence the default director with our host director
    proxy.Director = Director(d).Then(hostDirector(url.Hostname()))
    proxy.ModifyResponse = UpdateResponse
    http.Handle("/", proxy)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil))
}
```

Comment: It doesn't show it in the browser, or in the raw response? Because if you're just looking in the browser, you likely won't see your added text because you're prepending it to an HTML file, before the doctype or root tag, which is syntactically invalid and may be discarded by the browser.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `ModifyResponse` code is not modifying the response. In your code, you have:

```
r.Write(bytes.NewBufferString("monkeys"+html))
```

It seems that you are writing to the response, but nope. `r` is of `*http.Response` which has a `Write` method:

```
func (r *Response) Write(w io.Writer) error
```

The [document](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response.Write) says:

> Write writes r to w in the HTTP/1.x server response format, including the status line, headers, body, and optional trailer.

Since `bytes.Buffer` also implements a `io.Writer`, the code compiles, but instead of write to the response from the buffer, it write the response to the buffer, which is absolutely undesired.

The fact is, `http.Response` simply don't provide a way to modify its `Body`. It is clear that `Bodey` is an `io.ReadCloser`. What you can do is create a new `io.ReadCloser` with the body. Remember to change `Content-Length` field in the `Header` or it may cause problem.

```
func UpdateResponse(r *http.Response) error {
    b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    buf := bytes.NewBufferString("Monkey")
    buf.Write(b)
    r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(buf)
    r.Header["Content-Length"] = []string{fmt.Sprint(buf.Len())}
    return nil
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/_Tyvo6GVN3x

Comment: If HTTP upgrade to Websocket, can I get the length of the response?

Comment: It wasn't obvious to me but `r.Body` might be compressed. So simply appending or prepending may not work.